# How to type the same 'a' vowel kana twice on a smartphone with flick input?

Tags: discussion

[Flick input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_input_methods#Flick_input) - an input method commonly used with smartphones in Japan - allows you to flick a character in a direction to quickly type kana. Just tapping instead of flicking gives you a kana with the 'a' vowel. Tapping the same character more than once iterates through the vowels, in a loop. **How do you type the same 'a' vowel character twice?**

E.g. ああ, かか, ささ

The way I've been doing it, for as long as I can remember, is to tap the character once, add a space, a backspace and then type it again. I'm hoping there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you just need to turn off the old-style phone input, so tapping doesn't cycle through the available options anymore.  That way you can just tap あ twice in rapid succession to type ああ.

On an iPhone, you can set フリックのみ under the keyboard settings.  I'm sure you can do this on Android keyboards as well, although I don't have an Android phone myself.

Comment: There was a setting in Android 8 under [System] → [Languages & Input] → [Virtual Keyboard] → [Google Japanese Input] → [Keyboard Layout] → [Input style for 12 keys layout]